# How to run android application without eclipse plugin?

Tags: android

I m using console tools to build my android application. To do it, I use:

```
ant debug
adb install bin/MyApp.apk
```

and then I have to choose an aplication from menu in emulator. Is it possible to run already installed application in emulator with console command?

Comment: in the emulator click on applications and click on the application you installed in emulator already. i think this will help you dude.

Comment: this is exacly, what I dont like to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the `am` option in adb. I will try and find it in the manual if I have time, but maybe this will be enough for you to start?

This looks like a good start with some examples on how to start stuff from the commandline:
http://www.anddev.org/using_the_am-tool_start_activities-intens_from_a_shell-t368.html

Answer (score 3):

You can start a specific activity like this:

```
adb shell am start <INTENT>
```

To find out how to pass the intent, type `adb shell am`